# How to search strings inside files like in Windows without search monkey?

Tags: command-line, vmware, search, virtual-console

I am using Ubuntu on VMWare but I cannot connect to internet because of security restrictions.

I was wondering if there was a way to search for strings through the terminal and find which line the string is located on within the file.

Comment: Are you talking of [`grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/grep.1.html) or something more advanced?

Comment: Have u searched for it first.

Answer (score 120):

There are almost too many options to list

```
grep -r 'pattern_to_match' directory_to_search
```

Will output the file name and full line matching the pattern.

Answer (score 36):

The best I use is grep command with options -ri (Recursive and case insensitive search):

```
$ grep -r <text_pattern_to_search> directory_or_path_to_search
```

options that might be useful to you:

```
    -i - case insensitive
    -r, --recursive  like --directories=recurse
    -R, --dereference-recursive  likewise, but follow all symlinks
      --include=FILE_PATTERN  search only files that match FILE_PATTERN
      --exclude=FILE_PATTERN  skip files and directories matching FILE_PATTERN
      --exclude-from=FILE   skip files matching any file pattern from FILE
      --exclude-dir=PATTERN  directories that match PATTERN will be skipped.
```

> for deep info you can do `grep --help` or `man grep` in linux terminal.

Cheers

Answer (score 10):

If you want to find only line number where the sting is located within the file use this:

```
grep -n '/string_To_Find/=' directory/file_Name
```

If you want to find line number and also output the full line name where the string is located in the line use this:

```
grep -n 'string_To_Find' directory/file_Name
```

And if you only want to find full line name where the string is, use this:

```
grep -r 'string_To_Find' directory/file_Name
```